# How can I run code through all my csv files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I created a function and I want to apply it for multiple csv files.
How can I do it?

I have files with names like

```
rec2018_039.db.csv
rec2018_040.db.csv
```

I want to go through such files, do calculations and store as output files with such name:

```
rv_km_2018_039.db.csv
rv_km_2018_040.db.csv
```

The number that contains input file should be with the same number that the output file has.

```
import pandas as pd
import nearest_point as nearp
import numpy as np

filename_points = "F:\\merge_data_bases\\rec2018_039.db.csv"
out_filename_points = "F:\\trajectory\\river_km\\rv_km_2018_039.db.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename_points, delimiter=';')

df['river_km'], df['distance_to_ref_traj_meters'] = np.vectorize(nearp.river_km)(df['lat_deg'], df['lon_deg'], df['timestamp'])

'''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row.lat_deg, row.lon_deg)
    print(nearp.river_km(row.lat_deg, row.lon_deg)) 
'''

df.to_csv(out_filename_points, sep=';')
```

Now I changed the name of the file manually since I have more than 300 files but I should automize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to find the desired files. Then use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find the number pattern in order to create your output file. Then apply it in a loop:

```py
for file in glob.iglob("F:\\merge_data_bases\\*.db.csv"):
    r = re.search(".*?(\d+_\d+).db.csv$", file)
    if r:
        num = r.group(1)
    else:
        print("Wrong file encountered!")
        break
    outfile = "F:\\trajectory\\river_km\\rv_km_{}.db.csv".format(num)

    #  -----

    df.to_csv(outfile, sep=';')
```

Since we're already using regex to find the numbers, we could also skip the glob:

```py
for file in os.listdir("F:\\merge_data_bases"):
    r = re.search(".*?(\d+_\d+).db.csv$", file)
    if r:
        num = r.group(1)
        outfile = "F:\\trajectory\\river_km\\rv_km_{}.db.csv".format(num)

        #  -----

        df.to_csv(outfile, sep=';')
```